# how to install pgbadger: I am facing this problem

Tags: rpm, pgbadger

I tried installing pgbadger by doing the following 
`rpm -ivh pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`

and then I tried 
`yum install pgdg`

I am getting the error 
`No package pgdg available.`

Answer (score -1):

You got the message **No package pgdg available** as there are no such package called **pgdg**.

You need to install the package named **pgbadger**

For more details, please refer the [link](https://www.tutorialdba.com/2016/12/step-by-step-installation-of-pgbadger.html)

Comment: If I search using `yum search pgbager` I can see all the packages, but if I do `./pgbadger /var/log/pgsql -o test.html` neither did this.